# Webform 5.x lookup validation via data table lookup

Tags: webforms

I want to block/validate a new entry based on another submitted form

e.g.
[image]

If a site number has been used I want to block any new entry that wants to use that number?

Is this possible?

If so How?

Thanks all

Comment: Fantastic, it works perfect, so easy as well.

Just like to thank you for an outstanding product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Webform elements support unique value validation, which I should be able to address your requirement. If not, you may need to write a custom form alter hook with a custom validate callback.

[image: Element unique value validation]